# Will the "Third Place" be available for use in discussion during the beta phase?

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51, chat, beta-phase

Part of me wanted to tag this as a feature-request, because it would be nice, but I feel that if plans aren't already in place for this, then it isn't too wise to try and scramble it in.

We're only as far as the commitment phase, but I've been reading about the plans for when sites hit the closed beta. That's when we discuss all the colorful details of the future site, such as its real name, the FAQ, tagging nature, and other design stuffs. I agree with the idea of delaying this discussion until that stage, but then I started to wonder, "Where is this all going to happen?"

Are there plans for having the "Third Place" available by the time some of the sites are ready for the closed beta? Will we be able to use it for these site-detail casual discussions, allowing real-time deliberation on our subjects?

Comment: excellent question; I've flagged this internally.

Comment: @Marc: what do you mean by "flagged this internally"? Can questions be internally flagged? And what does it do?

Comment: @Kop: He means "I work for Stack Overflow, and think this is important enough to bring up with my team-mates." See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of a hard release date for the Third Place, yet, but it looks like the first Stack Exchange beta sites should hit in the next few weeks. The chat developers are brilliant but it doesn't seem likely the chat functionality could be completed, tested, and widely deployed before the first beta sites.

That being said, each site will have their own meta Stack Exchange. If meta.stackoverflow is any indication, I'm sure you guys will have no problem making good use of those forums.

Comment: each site will have its own meta?  Does that mean each site will use its own meta for discussion of on- and off-topic questions, approach to moderation, theme colors, etc, but all feature and bug requests across the sites would go to the SO meta, given that they'll all share the same technology?  And would the trilogy stay lumped together for meta?

Comment: @jaydles: Yes each site has it's own meta to discuss issues relating to that site. Network-wide/technology issues go to meta.stackoverflow.com. The Trilogy will have meta wherever it makes the most sense once everything settles in.

Comment: will meta already be available during beta? Couldn't it be used for discussion during commitment already?

Answer (score 1):

Current plans are ~4 weeks from right now, so that'd put this in early September.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/chat-now-in-public-beta/

Comment: This means BTW that he already has something, otherwise it would 6 to 8 weeks.