# Will the SE team be ready to launch, when the first site is at 100%

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase

I know there is a lot of work the SE team must to in order to get the next site up and running, but will you be ready to launch once 100% has been reached?

I must admit it is happening a lot quicker than I anticipated, but we are already at 89% on the [web app proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications?referrer=KGopogRECXM1). We might reach 100% some time tonight/tomorrow depending on your time zone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We're probably 10-14 days away from being ready to launch the first site into private beta.

The current plan is that private beta will last about a week, then the site will be in public beta.

We're sneakily slowing the progress indicator by multiplying it by 0.9 until then. So you won't notice.

Comment: (...except you might notice when it stalls at 90%)

Comment: ... and here I was going to make some snide remark about "but they get to write the code that defines the percentage, so it won't reach 100% until they're ready to launch"  ... and that's exactly the case.  Ha!  :)

Comment: Hmm, the first 90% is 90% of the work. The last 10% is 90% of the work. I guess that's how it works out.

Comment: 100% * 0.9 = 90% reached!

Comment: Does this also include that 'third' site for collaboration during the beta? Or is that still in undefined waters?

Comment: let the beta last 6-8 weeks...

Comment: @Tim See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53844/will-the-third-place-be-available-for-use-in-discussion-during-the-beta-phase) for official statement on the third place in the beta.

Comment: 100% * 0.9 = 90% reached! and now not only for [Web Applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57/web-applications) but also for [Gaming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming?referrer=OUkhLkjAueeU41zfK7oIpw2)

Comment: Is that 10-14 actual days, or 10-14 working days (assuming they let you guys have weekends off....) ;-)