# How often is the Area 51 commit percent re-calculated?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Given the Area 51 commit percentage is [based on the commiters' rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent) (and badges?) on the other sites, how often is this recalculated to take account of changes in rep and badges on the other sites and account associations?

Comment: Does it really matter?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54070/will-the-se-team-be-ready-to-launch-when-the-first-site-is-at-100/54072#54072

Comment: @Shane - Ha, hadn't seen that.  Still, it should matter once that's out of the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commit percentage is recalculated immediately when a user commits or uncommits.  However, we only sync the reputation & badge counts daily (or when a user first signs up).

**EDIT**

We also only sync for users with >200 reputation

Comment: is this really true? my reputation and badge count on area51 has remained static for days and I've been quite active lately.