# Do Area51 rep requirements track changes on trilogy sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51

If I understand correctly, an Area51 proposal in the committment phase needs to have committed users with a certain total point value, based on their reputations on other trilogy sites. But is it only the amount of reputation a user has *when committing* that counts toward that total, or is it always the most current amount? In other words, say I committed to a particular proposal when I have <strike>17.5k</strike> 9.6k rep on StackOverflow, but after a week, my SO reputation goes up to <strike>18k</strike> 10.7k. Does that increase in reputation get reflected into the total point value needed to get the Area51 proposal out of the committment phase?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54616/how-often-is-the-area-51-commit-percent-re-calculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time any user commits or un-commits, that proposal's commitment score is recalculated from scratch. So, yes -- the increase in your SO reputation is reflected by the commitment score (after someone commits or uncommits).

Comment: In addition, it is calculated once per day, at midnight UTC I believe, so...

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53650/area-51-commit-percent/53733#53733) answer

> - A user with no reputation gets a score of 1
> - A user with 200 reputation on 1 site gets a score of 1.7
> - A user with 200 reputation on 3 sites gets a score of 3.1
> - A user with 10000 reputation on 1 site gets a score of 7.2
> - A user with 10000 reputation on 3 sites gets a score of 19.6 (these are
>     extremely rare)

So, you won't have any difference for 17.5k to 18k up.

Comment: Thanks, but that kind of sidesteps the point of my question...

Comment: this reminds me of a joke I read the other day...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234419#234419