# Will increasing reputation on sites cause a recalc in the percentage of weight toward a commitment?

Tags: discussion, area-51, stackexchange-2.0, commitment-phase, site-proposal

As discussed in another question, the amount of weight someone's commitment to a Stack Exchange has is based on their reputation. Now if a user who currently has low rep works their way up, will the weight of their commitment be changed?

I realize that even having a lot of reputation doesn't seem to have a huge affect (I believe when a 60k rep user committed to one proposal, the increase in percentage was only 2-3%, and a 30k user only caused a 2% increase in readiness), but if you are able to go from <100 to 1k and add a percentage point or two, it would be possible to get people to participate on other exchanges for the sole purpose of getting another one closer to beta (which might or might not be a good thing - that's for a future discussion).

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54775/do-area51-rep-requirements-track-changes-on-trilogy-sites