# How is the user reputation on Area 51 calculated?

Tags: support, reputation, area-51

I was wondering when I'd hit the magic 40k mark on Area 51, so I did some manual calculations of my rep. What I found didn't add up.

For the calculations below, keep in mind that my rep according to A51 is **39180**.

#### What Area 51 shows:

```
   SO: 28265
  MSO: 10305
   SF:   248
------------
       38818
```

That's too low, so I thought I'd try the

#### Sum of displayed rep across all five sites:

```
     SO: 28470
    MSO: 10305
     SF:   248
     SU:   151
Area 51:   110
--------------
         39284
```

Now it's too high. Maybe I should try the

#### Sum of /reputation across all five sites:

```
     SO: 28432
    MSO: 10058
     SF:   248
     SU:   161
Area 51:   110
--------------
         39009
```

Too low again.

The only method I thought of that gets closer is taking the first number up there (38818) and adding in the undisplayed SU and A51 scores, which brings it to 39079.

So now I'm stumped. I'm sure it must be some combination of the above, but what?

And one thing that really puzzles me is the 28265 for SO rep. That is neither the displayed number nor the recalc'd number. Is it cached? And if so, why is my Meta score exactly what is displayed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We sum the reputation across all sites (including Stack Apps, as pointed out by [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55747/how-is-the-user-reputation-on-area-51-calculated/55749#55749)).  However, we only fetch the reputation once per day, so it can get out of sync.

In fact, Stack Overflow is a few days out of sync because of a bug that I'm fixing right now.

Comment: According to the tooltips on Area 51, my Meta reputation is 3772 (that was the value on June 11th) and my SO reputation is 1152 (some time before May 28th). So my SO is off by over a month, and my Meta by almost a month.

Comment: According to my [recent page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/13531?StartDate=2010-06-22&EndDate=2010-07-02) (assuming you as a dev can see it), I was at 28265 on June 22. So yeah, a few days out of sync would do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 39079 by one calculation, and the target reputation is 39180, you're missing exactly 101. Which happens to be the reputation for an associated account with no activity. Aside from your Stack Apps account (could that be it?), is there any other account you have that would have 101 reputation?

<s>Couldn't tell you where that 28265 comes from, though.</s>

According to my commitment on Gaming, I have 5342 reputation across all of the Trilogy sites. This seems... I don't have a good adjective for this.

Your reputation from other sites seems to be heavily cache'd. The [commitment percentage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54616/how-often-is-the-area-51-commit-percent-re-calculated) recalculates everyone's reputation whenever anyone commits or uncommits, but it seems that this only applies to the reputation used in the percentage calculation. The actual displayed reputation for that user seems to be not recalculated, so it seems you need to do some activity on Area 51 in order to get the proper display.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed that Stack Apps rep factored in there, but you're right, I do have a 101-rep account on SA. That's probably how it's calculated, but I am curious about the SO number.

Comment: @mmyers I think I may have some explanation. See my edit.