# Why aren't some users listed as participating in the Beta on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, beta-phase

I was checking out the [Area 51 list of participants in Gaming](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338/gaming), and I noticed that, for some reason, I'm not actually listed there. I've gotten 183 reputation with 8 posts (and perhaps, in something of a <s>bad omen</s> tradition, my non-applicable Meta reputation is higher from the get-go), so it is not as if I'm inactive. Furthermore, there are users who have had no activity at all that are listed. I've checked both under the reputation sort and under activity sort, I'm in neither.

Also noting, the question count and answer rate on Area 51 do include my content, so it knows about my contributions, but not *the user behind them*?

I checked the email for the private Beta, there wasn't anything that seemed to indicate that I needed to submit anything or go anywhere to participate. I've logged into Area 51, and used the "Visit" link to go to the Gaming site and that also hasn't changed anything. My email address is confirmed, too, as I have +50 on Area 51 for it. And it isn't that I'm logged in and it won't show me, as I first noticed this while I was logged off.

The user count on the site is 3 higher than that listed on Area 51, so I'm probably not the only one. What would cause someone to not be listed?

**Aside:** If you want to search for me [without getting banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56452/reviewing-user-pages-on-stack-exchange-area-51-beta-page-results-in-ip-banning), I would estimate my positions to be on Page 5 or 6 of the [reputation sort](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?page=5&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top), and Page 4 or 5 of the [activity sort](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?page=4&phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account association is in a semi-broken state at the moment. After clicking "Clear All Associations" from one of the trilogy sites, for example, you can't re-associate your Area 51 or private beta accounts.

@Grace Note, as a result, your Gaming account couldn't associate with Area 51, and therefore wasn't showing up in the list of beta users.

We are working on fixing account association across the board, so it should be working again soon. In the meantime, if you never click "Clear All Associations", everything should continue to work just fine.

If your associations are in a wonky state, a temporary workaround is to click "Clear All Associations" from Area 51, one of the trilogy sites, and any private betas you are in, and then start re-associating your accounts from scratch. @Grace Note, I went ahead and did this for your account, so you're showing up in the list of beta users now.

Comment: Huh, it seems that my Area 51 account had been decoupled for months. This also fixed the [problem with my Area 51 total reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55747/how-is-the-user-reputation-on-area-51-calculated/55749#55749). Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

My Google Account was logged into Area51, but attempts to visit the Cooking private beta wouldn't associate. I'd try to login with my Google openid and the login page would prompt me to create a new account on the site.

I went into my user profile in area51 and clicked "add openid". I re-added my Google account (even though it's the only associated openid), and then I was able to login to the private beta with the Google openid.