# Reviewing User Pages on Stack Exchange Area 51 Beta Page results in IP Banning

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, area-51, stack-exchange

I was reading [a recent Meta question about users not showing up on the Area 51 Stack Exchange 'users' page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/why-arent-some-users-listed-as-participating-in-the-beta-on-area-51) (the one that has to do with the Beta. Like the Gaming Beta User's page).  I was [paging through the beta users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1338?page=23&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top), and after the 8th or so page, was given the following error message:

It appears that since you guys use user flair, and the flair is rate limited, anyone who tries to view more than a few pages of users on the Beta page will be IP Banned for a specific amount of time.

[image]

Comment: Quit being so nosy (jk)

Comment: Is anyone else not seeing the image in this question? I saw it the first time, but now all I see is an "alt text" underlined link.

Comment: @Jon It used to be up, but right now it is broken for me as well.

Comment: @Jon @Grace Markdown doesn't like if you insert images and links and then insert links before it. It can't parse it.

Comment: @Jon, @Grace, oddly, I used to see broken links, and now can see it.

Comment: @jaydles I fixed it.  @Jon @Grace I opened a new bug: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/56460/markdown-cannot-parse-posts-with-added-links-when-there-are-images-with-links-in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We were loading each beta user's flair in an iframe, and with 10 iframes per page, quickly paging through the beta user list apparently hit the ~200 request/minute IP-ban limit.

This should be fixed now -- we eliminated the iframes and now serve the flair with the page instead.

Comment: Good deal. On careers we retrieved and cached the HTML fragment in the cache, and render it as part of the page. (when paging through candidates when flair was seen)