# I am not visible in area51 sites reputation/active list?

Tags: support, area-51

When I look to this page: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33?page=1&phase=beta&users=reputation#tab-top I don't see my account there, while it definitely should be (I have 258 repuatation on stats.stackexchange.com).

Also I am not appearing in the active list.

Why is that? Also when I am not logged in I don't see my name, so that isn't the problem...

Also Rich, Srikant Vadali, Stephen Turner are not visible and ~drpaulbrewer is shown as unknown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account association between the trilogy, Area 51, and beta sites is still in a semi-broken state.

@Peter Smit, I fixed your associations by following the steps in [my answer to a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/why-arent-some-users-listed-as-participating-in-the-beta-on-area-51/56479#56479).

Comment: NOTE to anyone else using this association-repair work-around: After following these steps, you will have to wait up to one hour before appearing in the beta user lists on Area 51.