# Some users not showing up in "top users" list on Area 51

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51

I noticed that not all "top users" from a beta site appear on the "Top Users" section on the beta tab in Area 51.  Does a user have to be registered on Area51 to show up on the Top Users list?

For an example, see users [Darin Sehnert](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/426/darin-sehnert) and [Papin](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/183/papin) of http://cooking.stackexchange.com.  As of right now, they both would be considered "top users" listed on Area51, but they don't show up on the list.

Comment: This is most likely related to the issues discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57978/i-am-not-visible-in-area51-sites-reputation-active-list) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/why-arent-some-users-listed-as-participating-in-the-beta-on-area-51). In summary, there seems to have been a decoupling of their associated accounts, so their Area 51 account isn't listening to the activity happening on the site. For example, see [Papin's account listing on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/7659?tab=accounts#tab-top).

Comment: @Grace thanks for the point. I don't think either of those users even *have* Area 51 accounts. That's a shame that they don't show up as "Top Users" on Area 51 because they both have lots of expert answers in their domain.

Comment: Papin does, but indeed it seems that Darin Sehnert doesn't. To me, though, that represents a very interesting dynamic - that a user who has no SE experience and joined after the private beta ended has actually climbed the ranks of users to be in the top. It's very interesting to see that happening, that we are attracting real experts from outside our midst.

Comment: @Grace I really do hope we attract experts from the outside. I'm not sure I'd be a huge fan of a cooking site dominated by professional programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, users only appear in Area 51's "Top Users" if they have Area 51 accounts.

**EDIT:** All users show up now.

Comment: What's the design thinking that drove this decision?  It's not really that bad; I'm just curious why the decision was made.

Comment: @Ben It was just the easiest way to implement it at the time, since we were already storing A51 users' info from other sites (for rendering multi-site flair). Plus, prior to the first public beta, there weren't any non-A51 beta users. We are planning on showing all the users on these lists, but it's only a medium-priority feature at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  That makes perfect sense.  I'm also glad to see the site has been updated to show users not registered on Area51. That's great!