# Why is my cumulative reputation shown on Area 51 less than my reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, area-51

My reputation on Stack Overflow is 152.  On Area 51 it says my total reputation across all sites is 86.  I think the 86 is roughly my reputation on all sites excluding Stack Overflow.

Why is my cumulative reputation on Area 51 less than my reputation on Stack Overflow?  Is this by design, or a bug?

Comment: Please check your [rep report](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) if the total rep is really 152.

Comment: Not sure why the rep report shows 142 and the badge shows 152.

Comment: I see the same thing - the cumulative total includes MSO rep but not SO rep even though all accounts show up as linked in my profile. Suits me as I have more rep here than there but I think that there is something not quite right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you recently do any funny business involving association and all that? If waiting a few hours as prescribed by [Diago's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62284/why-is-my-cumulative-reputation-on-area51-less-than-my-reputation-on-stackoverflo/62285#62285) aren't enough, consider dissociating and re-associating your Area 51 account with the rest of your accounts. [There have been some isolated instances where the Area 51 account was dissociated, so it would not receive further updates to its total reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/why-arent-some-users-listed-as-participating-in-the-beta-on-area-51).

Comment: I have not done anything involved with associations before.  I dis-associated all the sites and then re-associated it and that fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reputation on Area51 is heavily cached and only recalculated every few hours.

Comment: Reputation on stackoverflow.com has been over a hundred for 12 days.  So I think it is not a caching issue.