# Combined reputation on Area 51 is higher than the one shown in Stack Exchange flair

Tags: support, area-51, linked-accounts, flair

At one time Area 51 added all the sites' reputation. But it is not the case now if I am not mistaken. My reputation in Area 51 (in [Health Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6160/health)) is 1,447:

[image]

But my flair from Stack Exchange, for today, shows 1.3k:

[image: Stack Exchange flair, for January 8th 2012]

Why is this the case?

Comment: Those images are likely very, very, very heavily cached. After all, they're images, and images take a lot more effort (and inevitably bandwidth) to generate and save than to just display text. I see you've also earned 3 bronze badges since the image was updated as well.

Comment: I have observed this for a few days when there was absolutely no activity except me logging in and never were they in sync.

Comment: @Kishor: Yes, but these images probably only get updated like once a week or so, maybe 2. I don't know exactly, but I doubt it's very often.

Comment: @animuson, I doubt the images are created before they're used, so I guess they are created when first requested after being considered outdated. As the HTTP headers [yield](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackexchange.com%2Fusers%2Fflair%2F49686.png&submit=Submit&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0) `max-age=86400`, or 1 day, I would expect the flair image to be re-generated daily, not weekly. But at the same time, the headers also return `Expires: Thu, 08 Mar 2012 12:10:36 GMT` which is 2 months from now. Confused...

Comment: The flair image should be updated [at least once per 24-36 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/flair-not-updated/69403#69403). (@Matthew)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should combined flair match Area51 flair?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65695/should-combined-flair-match-area51-flair)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area 51 normally shows the reputation in all your sites (where the reputation is at least 200), under "total rep"; what shown under the link to your Area 51 profile is more complicated.
As far as I know, the flair only shows the sites where the reputation is higher than 200, while Area 51 could shows the reputation for those sites where it is lower than 200. If you have enough sites with a reputation of at least 200, sites where your reputation is lower than 200 are not included in the user reputation shown from Area 51 (the reputation shown under the Area 51 profile's link); there is also a limit of 6 sites.

Take as example [this user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/44448/brad-koch). That user's reputation is shown as in the following screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Brad Koch's reputation on Stack Overflow is 392, and that is the only site where his reputation is at least 200. 548 is the sum of the reputation on Stack Overflow, and Area 51.

[This user](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/3464?tab=accounts) doesn't have a reputation of at least 200 on any site, but Area 51 reports his reputation as in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

The shown reputation is not 0. In this case, I am not able to understand which SE sites are considered. The sum of reputation in all the sites where the user has an account, including where the reputation is lower than 200, is 402. I cannot find three numbers between 108, 95, 85, 63, and 51 whose sum is 212; the closer I can get is 222 (108+63+51), but I cannot understand in which way those three numbers are chosen. The numbers I summed are the reputation of Area 51, and two sites with the older accounts created by the user (2 years ago). Maybe the difference can be explained from the fact the data is cached.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. My reputation in the flair is the sum of reputation on SO+SU+Meta, which is 1296. So adding this to Area51 reputation of 151 makes this 1447 which is what is show in the Proposal Commitment page. Thank you.

Comment: As for "total rep", that [includes the reputation of referred other users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53691/what-is-the-total-reputation-field-on-area51), which applies to the first example user. (Look at the different values for that vary same user: [599 on The Great Outdoors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qWOYB.png) and [548 on Sports](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wkcw8.png). Both have 548 below the avatar.)

Comment: As for caching: the team lead [once wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55747/how-is-the-user-reputation-on-area-51-calculated/55756#55756) *"we only fetch the reputation once per day, so it can get out of sync"*. I doubt that explains it...

Comment: Just for the record: today Simon is [still showing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dysen.png) the very same unexplained high reputation at [The Great Outdoors](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659?phase=commitment): 212. But the 63 for Stack Overflow has increased to 68, so I'd say that is not included. Still, with 108, 95, 85, 68, and 51 and no referrals the closes I get now is 95 + 68 + 51 = 214.

Comment: Today, Simon [shows 1,000](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0RBBe.png), being 586 for the Great Outdoors itself, 213 for Super User and 201 for Area 51. These 3 sites are also shown [as icons in the flair](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659?page=14&phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top), and hovering those shows those numbers. So all seems to be resolved for that user.