# Does gaining reputation boost your commitment percentage on Area51?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How often is the Area 51 commit percent re-calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54616/how-often-is-the-area-51-commit-percent-re-calculated)

I'm earning quite a bit of reputation on SE sites across the network and I'm wondering if it affects the current commitment percentage of proposals I'm committed to.

For example, say **Proposal X** is at 32% commitment and I earn (somehow) 32k rep. in one day. Will it bump the commitment percentage up to 33%, 34%, etc. ?

Comment: That's the rep cap on 16 sites, but with accepted answers and bounties, you could probably do it on 10. Better start at midnight.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54616/how-often-is-the-area-51-commit-percent-re-calculated

Answer (score 1):

Yes, give or take rep cap. I had a lot of fun pushing GIS along this way. I ran a sort of rep bake sale on their behalf, answering any damn thing and posting a few questions.