# Has the commit calculation been modified?

Tags: discussion, area-51

It seems like a number of proposals just suddenly moved to 100% commit, and one that I'm following jumped from 29% to 33% with the addition of one new commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They were fudging the calculations - [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54070/will-the-se-team-be-ready-to-launch-when-the-first-site-is-at-100/54072#54072).

So I'm guessing that they've removed the fudge now that WepApps has successfully moved to public beta.

Comment: ah: so my almost 30% became 30% * 1.1 = 33%. makes sense.