# When will Stack Exchange proposals go beta?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will the SE team be ready to launch, when the first site is at 100%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54070/will-the-se-team-be-ready-to-launch-when-the-first-site-is-at-100)

I was just wondering if you were manually holding back proposals from reaching beta, since I can't imagine the Web Apps proposal needs more commitment.

Gathering from what Robert mentioned in [a question about the Third Place:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53844/will-the-third-place-be-available-for-use-in-discussion-during-the-beta-phase/53879#53879)

> I'm not aware of a hard release date
>   for the Third Place, yet, but it looks
>   like the first Stack Exchange **beta
>   sites should hit in the next few
>   weeks.** The chat developers are
>   brilliant but it doesn't seem likely
>   the chat functionality could be
>   completed, tested, and widely deployed
>   before the first beta sites.

I reckon you're just keeping it at 90% until your ready for beta? And  **is there a more accurate estimate for the beta launch?**

Bonus question: who will be in the private beta? Just the committers or do you cherry pick them?

Comment: Joel [said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54072), they are 10 - 14 days behind to release private beta, at Jun 17.

Comment: Jeez how do people manage to phrase such a question without getting any of the words the same...