# What's the threshold for getting to beta on area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Will the SE team be ready to launch, when the first site is at 100%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54070/will-the-se-team-be-ready-to-launch-when-the-first-site-is-at-100)
>   [Are Area51 Proposals Capped at 90% Commitment Currently?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54217/are-area51-proposals-capped-at-90-commitment-currently)
>   [When will Stack Exchange proposals go beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54561/when-will-stack-exchange-proposals-go-beta)

I'm curious, since the most active site on area51 right now has over 300 commitments, but it's been stuck at 90% for a long time. Are they being held because the "beta" phase isn't ready, or is there some subtlety to the algorithm that's not apparent?

Comment: See Joel's answer to the linked question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54070/will-the-se-team-be-ready-to-launch-when-the-first-site-is-at-100/54072#54072

Comment: Apparently this should be mentioned somewhere on area51, as it wasn't quite as sneaky as Joel had hoped

Comment: I searched but did not find :(. Anyway, now I know.

Comment: Don't worry too much about having not found this particular case. As [Ivo pointed out](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54561/when-will-stack-exchange-proposals-go-beta), people have a surprising ability to phrase the same concept in too many differing ways.